# contourf result differs when switching axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I am plotting a contourmap. When first plotting I noticed I had my axes wrong. So I switched the axes and noticed that the structure of both plots is different. On the first plot the axes and assignments are correct, but the structure is messy. On the second plot it is the other way around.

Since it's a square matrix I don't see why there should be a sampling issue.

Transposing the matrix with z-values or the meshgrid of x and y does not help either. Whatever way I plot x and y correctly it keeps looking messy.

Does anybody here know any more ideas which I can try or what might solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the sampling. Although the arrays have the same size, the stepsize in the plot is not equal for x and y axis.